# Can Delphi's Code Formatter be called automatically every time a file is saved?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

We are starting to use Delphi's Code Formatter to unify the format of everyone involved in our new project. The problem with the built-in Code Formatter is that, as far as we can see, it must be called manually, but plenty of times someone forgets to do so.

Is there a configuration, script, or something that would force the Code Formatter to run every time we save a file on the IDE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do certainly use a version control system where developers check-in the code after they have made a change.

Every good version control system has options to automatically perform commands on files before they are checked in. The Delphi IDE comes with the ["formatter.exe"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Formatter.EXE,_the_Command_Line_Formatter) commandline tool that you can use to format Delphi source code during check-in in your version control system.

Comment: Thanks, that would work. We use SourceTree and Tortoise GIT, I'm going to check it.